# sed or awk for resizing a comma field length as a function of another field's length

Tags: awk, sed, split, resize, field

I have a csv file with a varying initial comma field length, and a second comma field of fixed length.  I am trying to resize the second comma field length to be dependent on the first field length, eg (length of 2nd field) = (15 - (length of 1st field)).  This fixes the sum total of the first 2 fields of commas.

I have attempted to create some field delimiters by inserting a space between a comma and a non-comma, but it produced spaces between all the commas, and between BOL/EOL as well.

Perhaps there is a solution that does not require first inserting spaces as field delimiters, but I have not found a thread in the stackoverflow site that looks like it will work.

Example "myscv" (3 sample lines) :

```
^,somefilename1,,somefoldername1,\n

^,,somefilename2,,somefoldername2,\n

^,,,somefilename3,,somefoldername3,\n
```

wants to be :

```
^,somefilename1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername1,\n

^,,somefilename2,,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername2,\n

^,,,somefilename3,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername3,\n
```

Creating initial space field delimiters between comma and non-comma using sed :

> > sed 's/([,^,])/ & /g' mycsv

produces :

```
^ , somefilename1 , , somefoldername1 , \n

^ , , somefilename2 , , somefoldername2 , \n

^ , , , somefilename3 , , somefoldername3 , \n
```

I have managed to modify the line content to add spaces as delimiters using sed :

sed 's/,,*/ & /g'

piping to a 2nd can remove the leading space at the newline :

sed 's/^ //g'

still looking for an awk means of resizing the 2nd field of commas...

Comment: Sorry, I had not refreshed screen to see solutions before modifying the post!

Answer (score 1):

Given input file

```bash
$ cat file
,somefilename1,,somefoldername1,
,,somefilename2,,somefoldername2,
,,,somefilename3,,somefoldername3,
```

Then, using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) we can shift the fields around

```bash
awk -v total=15 '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    {
        tmp = $(NF - 1)
        $(NF - 1) = ""
        NF = total
        $(total-1) = tmp
        print
    }
' file
```

produces

```
,somefilename1,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername1,
,,somefilename2,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername2,
,,,somefilename3,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername3,
```

Comment: pretty elegant solution redefines the last original field as a temporary variable then creates the rest of the preceding fields as empty fields - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` solution utilises back referencing in order to subtract the first set of comma delimiters from the second set.

```
$ sed "s/,\+[^,]*,/&$(printf ',%.0s' {1..15})/;s/\(,\+\)\([^,]*\),,\1/\1\2/" input_file
^,somefilename1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername1,\n

^,,somefilename2,,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername2,\n

^,,,somefilename3,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername3,\n
```

- `s/,\+[^,]*,/&$(printf ',%.0s' {1..15})/;` - Collect all available commas at the start of the line and then jump to the next available comma and insert 15 additional commas with `printf`
- `s/\(,\+\)\([^,]*\),,\1/\1\2/` - collect all commas in the first field with the first capturing group within the parenthesis. Proceed to remove the fixed delimiters followed by subtracting the amount of commas contained in the first set of delimiters with the backreference `\1` which returns the buffer of the first capture group by excluding them outside the capturing group parenthesis.

Comment: I appreciate the use of sed to do this but could use some help with explaining the syntax

Comment: @jrunner Please check edit

Answer (score 0):

your description is somehow confusing (what do you mean with a field or field length?) but based on the example input/output I guess this is what you're looking for

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                       if($i!="") {n=15-i; break} 
                     t=$(NF-1); $(NF-1)=""; NF+=n; $(NF-1)=t}1' file

,somefilename1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername1,
,,somefilename2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername2,
,,,somefilename3,,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername3,
```

find the position of first nonempty field. Based on the position index append some number of empty fields before the penultimate field.

Answer (score -1):

single pass, no-loop, no-counting no-regex no-array `awk`-based solution :

```
 {m,g}awk 'NF+=($(___-!_)=$(__=NF-!_))^($__=_)'  FS=',' OFS=',' ___=15 

     or even more concisely

 {m,g}awk '($(__-!_)=$--NF ($NF=_))^!++NF' FS=',' OFS=',' __=15

 ,somefilename1,,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername1,
 ,,somefilename2,,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername2,
 ,,,somefilename3,,,,,,,,,,somefoldername3,
```